# javascript cannot access dom

Tags: python, google-maps, flask

I have this piece of code that works in vanilla js but it does not work in Flask template engine.

in the basic HTML-JS it does not have a problem whatsoever but somehow I think there's something I missed in Flask. Is there anything that I missed?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block content %}

<body>

    <div id="map"></div>





     <script type="text/javascript">
        function initMap(){

            let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                center: { lat: -8.6478, lng: 115.1385 },
                zoom: 14,
              });

              alert("from initmap");

              var pointOfInterest = [
                {
                  position: {lat: -8.6595, lng: 115.1301},
                  price : '1000000',
                },
                {
                  position:{lat: -8.654355373797795, lng: 115.12441781895892},
                  price: '49999999'
                }
              ]

                pointOfInterest.map(prop =>{
                    console.log(prop);
                })


        }



    </script>
    <script
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[redacted]&callback=initMap&v=weekly"
    async
    ></script>


</body>
{% endblock content %}
</html>
```

the api key has no problem whatsoever, but I cannot show the google map in the div.

Comment: Please define "does not work". Do you see the JavaScript rendered in the document? Are there differences from what you expect? Is there an error in the JavaScript console? If you put an alert into the script, outside `initMap`, does it trigger? How about inside `initMap`? What is the status code of the maps.googleapis.com request in the Network panel?

Comment: (Unrelated, but you might want to remove the API key from the template and replace it with a variable; then initialise that variable from environment, or a config file that is not committed into the repository)